# Realm in React Native loses data when the application is closed in Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm, apple-m1

I implemented `realm "11.3.0"` in React Native `"0.70.6"` using a singleton and using it to perform CRUD operation with the realm, the data stored in each schema can be stored, read, updated, and deleted without problems while using the application, but when the application is closed all, absolutely all the data is lost.

***realm configuration:***

```js
import Realm from 'realm';
// import schemas

let realmInstance: Realm;

export const getRealmInstance = async () => {
  if (!realmInstance) {
    realmInstance = await Realm.open({
      schemaVersion: 1.1,
      path: 'localOnly.realm',
      inMemory: false,
      schema: [
       // add schemas
       ...Regulations,
      ],
    });
  }
  return realmInstance;
};
```

***schema implementation:***

```js
import {ObjectSchema} from 'realm';

export const RegulationItemSchema: ObjectSchema = {
  name: 'RegulationItem',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    text: 'string',
  },
};

export const RegulationSchema: ObjectSchema = {
  name: 'Regulation',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    items: 'RegulationItem[]',
  },
};

export default [RegulationSchema, RegulationItemSchema];
```

***Use:***

```js
import {getRealmInstance} from '@realmdb/realmConfig';

export const createARegulation = async (regulation: NecessaryRegulation): Promise<void> => {
  const realm = await getRealmInstance();
  realm.write(() => {
    realm.create<Regulation>(
      'Regulation',
      regulation,
    );
  });
};

export const getRegulations = async (): Promise<
  Regulation[] | undefined
> => {
  const realm = await getRealmInstance();
  const regulations = await realm.objects<Regulation>('Regulation');
  if (necessaryRegulations) {
    return JSON.parse(
      JSON.stringify(regulations),
    ) as Regulation[];
  }
  return undefined;
};

// more code
```

And yes, this way I can perform CRUD operations while the app is in the first run, but when I close the application and reopen it is where all the realm data is **lost**.

I tried to solve it with the following steps

- change the version of "realm": "11.0.0" to version "11.3.0" (No success)
- Add 'path' to the `Realm.open` configuration with the variables: path: 'appDB.realm' and path: 'localOnly.realm'.
- Add to `Realm.open` configuration `inMemory: false`,

For this case, I am only testing on Android OS versions 11 and 13, both on emulators and physical devices.

I also tried making an APK build and installing it on a device but still lost data in the same way.

This is the configuration I have:

- Node: v16.17.0
- npm: 8.15.0
- "react-native": "0.70.6"
- "realm": "11.3.0"
- OS: macOS Ventura 13.x.x M1

Comment: Some troubleshooting may help. Realm stores its data in a Realm file; have you looked to see if the file exists at its proper path? This `if (necessaryRegulations) {` should be removed for troubleshooting and replaced with code that output the contents of regulations to console right after this line `const regulations = await realm`. You could add a temporary button to the app to read the realm file and output it's path and contents to see if it's valid. Are you calling [useRealm()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/use-realm-react/#userealm--) anywhere?

Comment: Were-you able to fix this problem? We have the same issue.